# Blocking calls on windows-phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to develop an application for win phone 7, which will allow the user to automatically block a call based let's say on phone number? I've read on a website that the current version doesn't allow 3rd party apps to interfere over calls or sms. Is it true?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the information you've read is correct: the current API does not allow you to do such interception of "call in progress" or any other interaction with the phone part, for that matter!

The only way you'd be able to do this is doing some sort of native code, but the phones have locked out this type of development, so right now doesn't seem to be any solution available...